# How can I display a <b:iconAwesome> instead of a <b:commandButton>?

Tags: css, jsf, bootsfaces

I'd like to know, if there is any way to replace the default button of `<b:commandButton>` with a `<b:iconAwesome>`.

However, it does work with a `<h:commandLink>`, perfectly.

```
<h:commandLink>
    <b:iconAwesome name="arrow-down"></b:iconAwesome>
</h:commandLink>
```

And with replacing, I mean fully replaced and not, that the icon is on the button. Just check the working code above.

Are there other hints to be mentioned?

(Note: `<b:...>` is a component of BootsFaces.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers:

- To show an icon within a commandButton, just add the iconAwesome attribute:

  ```
  <b:commandButton value="" ajax="true" update="form:inform infoshow" 
                   iconAwesome="thumbs-up" look="info" />
  ```

[image: Example of a BootsFaces image commandButton]

- If you want to display the image instead of the button, while keeping the button functionality, add a couple of inline styles (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497094/remove-border-from-buttons)):

  ```
  <b:commandButton value="" ajax="true" update="form:inform infoshow" 
                iconAwesome="thumbs-up" look="info" 
                style="padding: 0; border: none; background: none;color: #000" />
  ```
- If you need more flexibility: we're already working on it. BootsFaces 0.8 is going to allow you to nest arbitrary HTML within the `<b:commandButton />`, exactly the way you did in your `<b:commandLink />` example. You can watch the progress on our bug tracker: https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/65

Comment: Well, I need to display the icon INSTEAD of the button, not on it. So just the icon with button functionality (as you can see in the `<b:commandlink>` example.)

Comment: @alexander: button functionality is also 'press' indication. Do you want that to? If not why not e.g. use css to remove that?

Comment: Well, I tried it, it didn't work. I used all states (hover,active..etc). Well, with the `<b:commandLink`, it does work nicely - so there is a missing feature or whatever.

Comment: I just tried in Chrome's developer tool. I managed to replace the button by the image using CSS. My solution is not perfect yet - there are a couple of odd pixels below the image - but it clearly shows the way. I've updated my original answer.

Comment: Perfect! I'm really glad, you could help me out (again and again!).