# Achieve "::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to remove the ugly focus outline on an input button in firefox. I've tried adding `::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}` as style in my html, which works initially, but not when button elements are re-created via javascript.

I've tried:

```
cell.style.mozFocusInner.border = "0";
cell.style["-moz-focus-inner"] = "{border:0}";
cell.style["-moz-focus-inner"]["border"] = "0";
```

etc.

In general, how do I "map" css to javascript?

Comment: And if you add `!important` in your css ?

Comment: You mean this https://www.kirupa.com/html5/setting_css_styles_using_javascript.htm ? See section *Setting the Style Directly* in the link ...

Comment: !important still doesn't work when new buttons are added via javascript

Comment: it also doesn't work if I put the script before the style in the html. disclaimer: I'm completely new to CSS

Comment: @ralfhtp thanks, that's helpful, but have I not already tried that with the element style assignments above? I must be getting something wrong, perhaps with the "{border:0}"?

Comment: maybe try `border:none` like in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497094/remove-border-from-buttons

Comment: You can't style pseudo-elements like this. You can insert a new stylesheet and use a `::-moz-focus-inner` selector. See [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/311052/1529630)

Comment: Using 
`sheet.insertRule('::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}', 0);`, where sheet is taken from here: https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets , worked. @Oriol would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CSS property to IDL attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#css-property-to-idl-attribute) algorithm, a `-moz-focus-inner` would be camelCased to `MozFocusInner`. So you could use one of

```
element.style.MozFocusInner = value;
element.style.setPropertyValue('-moz-focus-inner', value);
element.style.setProperty('-moz-focus-inner', value);
element.style.setProperty('-moz-focus-inner', value, '!important');
```

But there is a **big problem**: `-moz-focus-inner` is not a CSS property, is a pseudo-element.

Given an element, you can read the computed styles of its pseudo-elements via [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Use_with_pseudo-elements):

```
getComputedStyle(element, '::-moz-focus-inner').borderTopWidth; // 1px
```

However, you can't set them directly. If you want to do that, you can:

- Conditionally set the desired styles in a stylesheet, and use JS to trigger that condition whenever you want. For example, add a class.

  ```js
  document.getElementById('enable').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('target').classList.remove('no-focus-inner');
  });
  document.getElementById('disable').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('target').classList.add('no-focus-inner');
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .no-focus-inner::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ol>
    <li><button id="enable">Enable inner outline</button> or <button id="disable">Disable inner outline</button></li>
    <li>Press Tab key</li>
    <li><button id="target">Focus me to check if I have inner outline</button></li>
  </ol>
  ```
- Create a new stylesheet with the desired rulesets, and append it to the document.

  ```js
  var styleSheet = document.createElement('style');
  styleSheet.textContent = '#target::-moz-focus-inner { border: none; }';
  document.getElementById('enable').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(styleSheet.parentNode) document.head.removeChild(styleSheet);
  });
  document.getElementById('disable').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
  });
  ```

  ```html
  <ol>
    <li><button id="enable">Enable inner outline</button> or <button id="disable">Disable inner outline</button></li>
    <li>Press Tab key</li>
    <li><button id="target">Focus me to check if I have inner outline</button></li>
  </ol>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works without javascript: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/button-padding-issue/

`::moz-focus-inner` is a pseudo-element. In this link are several ways how to modify pseudo-elements dynamically (with javascript) http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/

*cited from http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/* :

```
<p class="red">Hi, this is a plain-old, sad-looking paragraph tag.</p>

.red::before {
    content: 'red';
    color: red;
}
```

**Method 1**

Write separate classes attached with pseudo element for each style and then using JavaScript or jQuery toggle between these classes.

```
.green::before {
    content: 'green';
    color: green;
}

$('p').removeClass('red').addClass('green');

...
```

Common css-styles (not pseudo-elements) can be modified using javascript like this:

*cited from https://www.kirupa.com/html5/setting_css_styles_using_javascript.htm* :

*Every HTML element that you access via JavaScript has a style object. This object allows you to specify a CSS property and set its value. For example, this is what setting the background color of an HTML element whose id value is superman looks like:*

```
var myElement = document.querySelector("#superman");
myElement.style.backgroundColor = "#D93600";
```

*To affect many elements, you can do something as follows:*

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");

for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.opacity = 0;
}
```

*In a nutshell, to style elements directly using JavaScript, the first step is to access the element. I am using the `querySelector` method to make that happen. The second step is just to find the CSS property you care about and give it a value. Remember, many values in CSS are actually strings. Also remember that many values require a unit of measurement like* *px* *or* *em* *or something like that to actually get recognized.*

Comment: Could you please specifically answer to how translate `::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}` into javascript?

Comment: How is this related to the question? OP wants to style a pseudo-element, not an element nor a bunch of elements.

Comment: In this link http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/ is a way to modify pseudo-elements using javascript, i will edit the answer