# HTML show more text on button click using javascript

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I am trying to put a read more button into all my pages but it's not quite working properly. It shows all the text initially, then when it's clicked once it works properly. Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong? I'd also like to know how to format the look of the button too please.

The page is here - https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/sea-point-flower-delivery/

I am using the following code in HTML -

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
      var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
      if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
        moreText.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
      }
    }
```

```css
  .moretext{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
 <div class = "textcontainer">
    <br>
    <br>
    <H3> SHOW YOUR LOVE WITH FLOWERS </H3>
    <p>
    <br>
    When you send flowers, it’s a deeply personal gesture of affection, we realise this well. Receiving a gift of flowers is intensely memorable to someone, because it makes them feel very special and loved. Flowers For Everyone gives you the assurance that we get it right, every time.
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="dots"></span><span id="more">
    We have a striking range of luxury flower bouquets freshly cut & hand-delivered across the Western Cape province; from Sea Point with its breathtaking sea views and trendy restaurants, to the Cape winelands and beyond, we put smiles to faces. 
    <br>
    <br>
    </span></p>
    </div>
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">More...</button>
```

Comment: You made a typo `more` and `moretext` are not the same

Comment: **Warning**: `<br>` is not a substitute for margins!

Comment: **Warning**: Writing text in ALL CAPS can lead to screen readers treating it like an initialism and spelling it out, letter by letter. Write normally and use CSS's `text-transform` to control how it looks.

Comment: **Warning**: `<br>` is not a substitute for `<p>`. If you have multiple paragraphs then write multiple paragraphs. Don't write one paragraph with lots of double line beaks in it.

Comment: Three full stops (`...`) is not the same as a horizontal ellipsis (`…`) even if it looks visually similar. If you can't type … on your keyboard, then look to HTML's `&hellip;` entity.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll look into all these things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can should add class="moretext" to your span this way the text will be hidden initaly like this

```
<span id="more" class="moretext">
```

In the css add the floowing lines padding: 0;
border: none; like this for your button

```
#myBtn
{
padding: 0;
border: none; like this
}
```

Answer can be found here [Remove border from buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497094/remove-border-from-buttons)

Comment: Thanks.. How do I format the button? I just want it to say read more with no border

Comment: Your welcome Michelle I am unsure want you mean by no border can you elaborate what is it you want with no border? the button?

Comment: I have changed my answer. Is this want you wanted?

Comment: Do you know why this button doesn't work on the mobile device?

Comment: No sorry, I don't know why you should ask a new question for it.